# Using GNU Screen to open GUI window on remote desktop

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen

I've been trying to figure out how to open PyCharm on a computer that I ssh into and send that window to the computer I am currently using.

The desired behavior is:

From Computer A: in terminal, SSH into Computer B

From Computer A: open PyCharm on Computer B

On Computer B: opens PyCharm, sends window to computer A

From Computer A: view and control PyCharm on Computer B.

I can achieve this behavior with `ssh -Y [computer B address]` followed by the terminal command to launch PyCharm. I keep hearing that it's "easy" to do this with GNU Screen, but I can't seem to find the right commands. How do I do it? Is it actually possible?